# How to install dependencies for OpenCV?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV by following the instructions on: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

When I run: `sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev`

I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 

                  Depends: libswresample-dev (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 

libavformat-dev : Depends: libavformat-ffmpeg56 (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed 

                   Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 

                   Depends: libswresample-dev (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 

libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.30-1ubuntu1) but 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 is to be installed 

                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed 

                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed 

                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed 

                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed 

                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed 

                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed 

                 Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed 

libswscale-dev : Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 

                  Depends: libswscale-ffmpeg3 (= 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2) but 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have Googled each dependency individually, but not able to find anything that works.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: "E: Unable to correct problems, *you* have held broken packages."

Comment: I was just following the instructions mentioned in https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html . Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you pointing to any other repositories apart from the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just not able to solve this problem, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.0/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso), and I was able to run `sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev` without any errors.